# App store регистрация

Tags: ios, appstore

Я разрабатываю приложение для компании по предоставлении бытовых услуг. Могу ли я опубликовать его на своем аккаунте разработчика, или нужно регистрировать отдельно аккаунт компании?

Comment: Если компания, для которой Вы делаете приложение с такой постановкой вопроса согласна, то почему нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

не самая лучшая идея, в первую очередь для заказчика - от кирпича никто не застрахован, если им жалко тратится, то в случае если вы окажитесь вне зоны досягаемости, или они захотят чтобы следующею версию  делал кто то другой то кто им айболит ?

Comment: Меня интересует не возникнут ли проблемы при публикации и во время рассмотрения? Или не обязательно иметь аккаунт компании чтобы опубликовать подобное приложение.

Comment: Если вопрос который Вы задали об юридических правах на торговую марку то нет, не возникнут.

Answer (score 2):

На­ша ком­па­ния очень дол­го ре­ги­стри­ро­ва­лась в App Store, и этот пост нам кое в чем по­мог. Мы на­пи­са­ли це­лую ис­то­рию про то, как ре­ги­стри­ро­ва­лись, мо­жет, ко­му при­го­дит­ся http://skycase.ru/blog/company-registration-appstore/

Answer (score 1):

Присоединяюсь к ответу и комментарию - истина есть в обоих.

Все зависит от степени вашей лояльности в отношении данной компании - насколько вы там свой, и наоборот, насколько они для вас свои. Если есть сомнения во взаимной дружбе навеки, лучше, не задумываясь, открывайте компанейский аккаунт (см. другой ответ - он про это).

Поделюсь личным опытом - когда я начал работать над своим текущим приложением, мне просто был вручен "их" аккаунт, притом не компанейский, а просто аккаунт, созданный их ведущим разработчиком. Со своей стороны компания поступила абсолютно правильно, а я этому, конечно, оказался рад не очень, так как, во-первых, "мне не дают спокойно держать всю iOS-часть под контролем", а, во-вторых, наличие двух и более аккаунтов приводит к разным неудобствам в использовании Xcode, необходимости часто переключать аккаунты: моего и "их", вот пара примеров такого рода проблем:

1. Xcode 5 в бете доступен для зарегистрированных разработчиков (то есть для аккаунта вашей компании), а для вашего Apple ID он недоступен - конечно, это не страшно, - там все решается, - просто появляется дополнительная морока.
2. Проблема с написанием баг-репортов и assistance request'ов. Мне приходится быть внимательнее, с какого аккаунта я их посылаю, так как мне пару раз приходили ответы, что, мол, "мы не можем подтвердить, что вы действительно участник Apple Developer Program".

Итого, ваш аккаунт - удобнее вам, но неудобно компании, и наоборот.

Удачи в публикации)

Comment: Меня интересует не возникнут ли проблемы при публикации и во время рассмотрения? Или не обязательно иметь аккаунт компании чтобы опубликовать подобное приложение.